# OctoberCMS / Anonymous Global Scope

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I am use OctoberCMS Rainlab.User plugin to manage authentication.

I have various models and that belongTo User.

How do i set up an anonymous global scope on each model to only return the records that belong to the authenticated user?

Many thanks in advance for any help.

```
use Auth;

protected static function booted()
    {
        $user = Auth::getUser();
        static::addGlobalScope('user_id', function (Builder $builder){
        $builder->where('user_id', $user);
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a dynamic scope in the model's definition page. You can read more about it [here](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/model#query-scopes).

```
class PluginModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * Scope a query to only records with user.
     */
    public function scopeGetUserRecords($query, $userId)
    {
        return $query->where('user_id', $userId);
    }
}
```

Now any time you call your PluginModel class you can just do this:

```
$userRecords = PluginModel::getUserRecords($user->id)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly similar to how you do it in straight laravel as you already tried to do. You just add it to the model's boot function instead of booted.

```
protected static function boot()
{
  parent::boot();

  $user = Auth::getUser();
  static::addGlobalScope('user', function ($query) use ($user) {
    $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
  });
}
```